# CouchDB Server Fails To Start

Tags: couchdb

All of a sudden I can't get the CouchDB Server to start on my Mac (OS 10.8.2). It seemed to die for no reason and now it won't start, even after a reboot.

UPDATE: I'm using v1.2.0.

Here's the error log. I searched for 'eaddrnotavail' but didn't find anything that helped me. Any ideas?

```
error_report,<0.34.0>,
                 {<0.127.0>,crash_report,
                  [[{initial_call,
                     {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                    {pid,<0.127.0>},
                    {registered_name,[]},
                    {error_info,
                     {exit,eaddrnotavail,
                      [{gen_server,init_it,6,
                        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,313}]},
                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
                    {ancestors,
                     [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.35.0>]},
                    {messages,[]},
                    {links,[<0.96.0>]},
                    {dictionary,[]},
                    {trap_exit,true},
                    {status,running},
                    {heap_size,1597},
                    {stack_size,24},
                    {reductions,453}],
                   []]}}
```

Comment: which version of couchdb do you use?

Comment: `eaddrnotavail` means that CouchDB (Erlang to be correctly) cannot assign requested address. Check up `[httpd]` config section for `bind_address` and `port` options. Had they setted correctly?

Comment: @kxepal I had figured that much out but couldn't think of anything I did that would have caused the problem. But your comment sent me searching for an appropriate config file which I found. And what do you know - I had changed the bind address. I did that through futon, but thought I had changed it back.

The file where the config stuff is stored is local.ini and I found it at:
/Users/bradrhoads/Library/Application Support/CouchDB/etc/couchdb

If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it so get the points:).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eaddrnotavail` error means that CouchDB (Erlang to be precise) cannot assign the requested address. You need to check your *local.ini* config file for `bind_address` and `port` parameters in the `[httpd]` section and ensure that they are set correctly.

As you noted in comments:

> I had changed the bind address. I did that through futon, but thought I had changed it back.

Changing bind address via Futon could render your CouchDB broken, because you may easily enter a malformed value which will be automatically applied. However, this case is [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1512) and in 1.3. CouchDB will first validate the specified address before applying changes and will provide a more concrete error message as "invalid_bind_address" if something is wrong. More details in [sources](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/commit/09ead8a070050141d8661500fc86e37e1e6a6c9a).

Comment: As I mentioned above, these settings are in a file called local.ini.